# NewStringUTF() with threads

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I want to transform XML from C++ to JAVA in JNI. First I transform only on a thread cost `160ms`, then I try to use 4 threads but cost the same time.

I find that using `NewStringUTF()` 5000 times cost `30ms` only on a thread, but `100ms` on 4 threads, can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: How often are you attaching and detaching the threads to the VM?

Comment: Presumably because there is a semaphore somewhere.

Comment: reply @Michael:70~80times